# Bridgeland-Stability Condition: Why is the Harder-Narasimhan filtration unique?

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

I'm trying to understand Bridgeland's notion of stability condition on a triangulated category as defined in Definition 1.1 of the paper [Stability conditions on triangulated categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212237.pdf).

See also Definition 3.3 in the same paper.
The decompositions of a non-zero object as in Definition 3.3(c) are the *Harder-Narasimhan* filtrations.

> **Question:** Why is the Harder-Narasimhan filtration of any non-zero object *unique* (up to isomorphism of the semistable factors)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct proof, assuming familiarity with the octahedral axiom (TR4) which asserts that whenever $g$ and $f$ are composable morphisms, there is an exact triangle whose vertices are $\text{cone}(f)$, $\text{cone}(g)$, and $\text{cone}(g\circ f)$.

Let $P$ be a slicing of the triangulated category $\mathscr{C}$, and for $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ write $P(I)$ to mean the extension closure of $\bigcup_{\varphi\in I} P(\varphi)$. For a collection of objects $\mathscr{C}'\subset \mathscr{C}$, write ${}^\perp\mathscr{C}'$ for the full subcategory $\{C\;|\; \text{Hom}(C,C')=0 \quad \forall C'\in\mathscr{C}'\}$ and note that this is closed under extensions (easy exercise in using the octahedral axiom.)

Suppose $0\neq C\in\mathscr{C}$ admits two filtrations

[[image: two commutative diagrams showing filtrations of <span class=]$C$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Faug.png)

with $E_i\in P(\varphi_i)$, $E_i'\in P(\vartheta_i)$. We argue by
induction on $n$.

**If $\mathbf{n=1}$,** then $C=E_1$ is semistable of phase
$\varphi_1$. Note we cannot have $\vartheta_i>\varphi_1$ for all
$i$, else $C\in P\{\vartheta_1,...,\vartheta_m\}\subset {}^\perp
    P(\varphi_1)$ giving a contradiction (we use the extension-closure of orthogonal complements here). Thus $\vartheta_m \leq
    \varphi_1$.

Claim equality holds; if not then the map $C\rightarrow E_m'$ vanishes and the final triangle splits as $C_{m-1}'\cong
    E_m'[-1]\oplus C$. It follows that
$$
        E_m'[-1]\in \langle E_1',...,E_{m-1}' \rangle \subseteq
        P\{\vartheta_1,...,\vartheta_{m-1}\} \subseteq {}^\perp
        P(\vartheta_m-1),
    $$
and hence $E'_m=0$, giving a contradiction (Bridgeland's original definition doesn't assert the semistable factors are non-zero but if we don't assume that then the uniqueness of filtrations can be broken trivially).

Thus $C$ and $E'_m$ are non-zero semistable objects of the same phase. If $m\geq 2$, then $C_{m-1}'$ is a non-zero object in $P\{\vartheta_1,...,\vartheta_{m-1}\}\subseteq {}^\perp P(\varphi_1)$ and hence the final triangle must split as $E_m'=C\oplus C_{m-1}'[1]$. But this gives a non-zero morphism $C_{m-1}'[1]\rightarrow E_m'$,
a contradiction. Thus $m=1$ and the two filtrations coincide.

**If $\mathbf{m,n\geq 2}$,** a similar argument shows $\vartheta_m=\varphi_n$ so that $E_m'$ and $E_n$ have the same phase. In particular,$\text{Hom}(C_{m-1}',E_n)=0$. Applying the octahedral axiom to the composite (zero) map $C_{m-1}'\rightarrow C \rightarrow E_n$ yields an exact triangle $C_{n-1}\rightarrow E_m'\rightarrow C_{m-1}'[1]\oplus E_n
\rightarrow C_{n-1}[1]$. Now we have the commuting diagram where the
existence of the dashed arrows follows from axiom (TR2) of triangulated categories.

[image]

It follows from the five lemma that the dashed arrows are in fact
isomorphisms, and the middle row can be used to extract an isomorphism
$C_{n-1}\rightarrow C_{m-1}'$. The result follows by induction.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that the filtrations are unique because they arise as factorization of an orthogonal, multiple factorization system: see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04658) §4.1.

The even shorter answer is that you can prove it for triangulated categories, but it's unsatisfying.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. The machinery in your reference seems to be too sophisticated. I would simply like to see a direct proof that the HN-filtration on triangulated categories is unique. Since you claim that this is true, how can one show this? It would be great if you could expand on your answer.